# Can't see my profile in the top ribbon

Tags: bug

I have been trying to go to my SO profile for so long but I can't see the button which shows my reputation. Here is a screenshot:

[image: SO website homepage]

In the top right-hand side, I can't see my reputation, my badges or my profile picture. How come I have this problem?

I have tried to refresh my browser many times now. I even reinstalled chrome.

Comment: Odd. You are clearly logged in. Do you have any extensions or user scripts that might be scrubbing this information out? What happens when you try to Inspect the approximate area?

Comment: @CodyGray I don't have any scripts running. I tried disabling all my chrome extensions and restarting chrome. What do you mean by try inspecting the area?

Comment: Right click -> Inspect. If you're a web developer, you'd know what I'm talking about. If not, no big deal. You'll have to wait for someone to come along that can diagnose the problem.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't know what you are talking about. So should I wait for someone else to try to answer the question?

Comment: Could you try to reproduce it from a mobile device? (Don't forget to click "full site" at the bottom)

Comment: @nicael I have tried logging in from another laptop, same problem. I have a Blackberry (Bold... don't judge) so I can't visit SO on it.

Comment: Hm, logged from another laptop and still the problem? That's strange indeed.

Comment: Does it also happen there, on Meta Stack Overflow?

Comment: @nicael Yeah, I have tried to go on other SE communities, same problem.